# Quantitatively Calculate Dipole Moment

Tags: physical-chemistry, electronegativity, dipole

Recently, I have been reading up on articles relating to the dipole moments of different molecules (specifically [this](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/%7Echem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/ESPotential/ESPdipoles.html)). I see how they can get bond lengths and experimental dipole moments with reasonable accuracy and compare that to the theoretically predicted values.

What I don't get is the how theoretical prediction of dipole moment happens. I know that dipole moment equals the charge times the separation distance (u=q*d). So I must be able to predict the dipole (making sure its a vector) of any molecule given its distance of separation and partial charge on the molecules. The partial charge on the molecule depends on the electronegativity values. But then you can't put the electronegativity values (Pauling or Sanderson or others) directly as charge in the formula. Now, I know that Pauling or any other electronegativity scale is only arbitrarily chosen and is relative to the most electronegative element.

But then, how do we make theoretical estimates of dipole moments? Is there any way of relating the electronegativity values to partial charge on each atom? Or is there an entirely different approach?

I have already read these StackExchange answers -  [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34897/relationship-between-dipole-moment-of-a-molecule-and-electronegativities-of-cons) which answers the 'how' but not by 'how much'

Comment: :/ Plug your molecule in some serious software that gets distances and partial charges right, and lo and behold...

Comment: Not possible to make a connection between electronegativity and dipole moments. Forget it. Dipole moments are theoretically calculated by advanced quantum mechanical calculations (which I cannot do), and experimentally determined by microwave spectra (again not a trivial exercise) and by various methods. Still experimental methods give a reliable value. Theoretical calculations are pretty close.

Comment: @Mithoron I have tried this method using ChemAxon's MarvinSketch. I would like to know how reliable are these estimates, and possibly verify it myself.

Comment: @M.Farooq Very well, if the method of theoretical calculation of dipole moments is a complex thing, then I would be happy to see a high level overview of the process even if it skips some details without obstructing the understanding of the process. I have not found any resource online explaining the process which I would be more than happy to receive if somebody points that out.

Comment: @PrajvalK There is a software called GaussView which allows you to calculate dipole moments for a given structure. You have look up its documentation. Please note not everything is available on the internet and most of the stuff is behind paywalls.

Comment: @PrajvalK, And here it is. https://gaussian.com/force/, I have never used it but my collaborators use it exactly for determining dipole moments.

Comment: @M.Farooq GaussView is just a GUI for Gaussian, which does the actual calculations. Funny that you are promoting closed-source software company with [shady practices](https://web.archive.org/web/20180810083536/http://bannedbygaussian.org/) and mentioning paywalls when there are a free alternatives such as [ORCA](https://orcaforum.kofo.mpg.de/app.php/portal) with [Avogadro](https://www.orcasoftware.de/tutorials_orca/first_steps/GUI.html) as graphical interface.

Comment: @PrajvalK I highly doubt ChemAxon's MarvinSketch could be considered *serious* in the context of Mithoron's comment and your use case.

Comment: @M.Farooq Yeah, I have heard about Gaussian but I do not have the pockets for it

Comment: @andselisk I might check with Avogadro or ORCA for its predictions. The whole reason this came up was that there was an anomaly between values that some websites gave and what the software gives which I will be addressing this in another post. For now, though I will leave this question open for any person in the future who might know the actual process.

Comment: @andselisk Most people in computational chemistry I have met seem to only know about and use Gaussian, probably because it was developed a long time ago, and there is inertia in adopting new softwares. Orca is a good software and there is also GAMESS, NWChem etc. which are all free.

Comment: @Mithoron The software does not usually calculate the partial charges, the dipole moment can be directly calculated from wavefunction. Partial charges (e.g. ESP charges) are generated by a separate fitting procedure, which is not required for dipole moment calculation. OP, take a look at this page: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31075/how-to-calculate-molecular-dipole-moment-from-a-known-wavefunction

Comment: @SRMaiti Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for.